# AdControl error: No ad available No ad available. No additional information. In Microsoft Advertising for UWP App

Tags: xamarin, windows-store-apps, uwp, ads

I am making app of Xamarin UWP (Universal Windows Platform) and use Microsoft Advertising for mobile. For this I am using Link https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net

All thing is well, but problem is that when i am using their Test ApplicationId and AdUnitId, the ad will show and i use new created ApplicationId and AdUnitId then error is show- AdControl error: No ad available in developing mode. Please guide me..

Comment: did you try this before publishing your app into store?

Answer (score 1):

Your apps have been published in the store or not, **usually real Application Id and Ad unit Id value should apply from the published apps and it takes 1-2 days after that for ads from real units to start serving.** So I would like to suggest you use test value when you create your project, you just need to replace test value with real values when you package your project and submit in the store.

Comment: can you please extend your statement? I have my app in the store as submission 1 with banner ads. now i am extending for submission 2 with interstitial ads. I created an add in the developers backend and tried using app Id and AdUnitid but it didnt work, returns error. Do you mean that my app should be in the store with submission 2 that code is already integrated?

Answer (score 0):

The fill rate is very low for Windows ads, so it's not a problem with your code. Also, you won't see ads in developing mode, so you have to release your app in order to see the ads.